# How to become a specific user in ansible

Tags: ansible, su

I am trying to run a command on a system with ansible as a specific user.

Its important that I run as that specific user because the config file the command needs to work is only available to that user. Any other user won't be able to read the config file and thus won't work.

I'm trying to use ansible's `become_user`, `become` and `become_method` to run the command but ansible seems to be ignoring it.  Here's an example:

```
- shell: whoami
  register: c
- shell: whoami
  become: yes
  register: d
- shell: whoami
  become: yes
  become_user: myuser
  become_method: su
  register: e
- debug: var=c.stdout
- debug: var=d.stdout
- debug: var=e.stdout
```

And when I run the ansible script I get the following:

```
TASK [myscript : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.33.56.93] => {
    "c.stdout": "root"
}

TASK [myscript : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.33.56.93] => {
    "d.stdout": "root"
}

TASK [myscript : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.33.56.93] => {
    "e.stdout": "root"
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how `become_user` works? Is there some other way for me to get my command to run as a specific user?

I am using ansible 2.9.18 if that should matter.

Thanks

Comment: ```
become: true
become_user: <username>
become_flags: -i
shell: "whoami"
```

Comment: Adding become_flags: i doesn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: I've tried become_method: sudo. That also doesn't seem to help. No mater what I try I always appear to be running as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`become_user`** is the main piece that you need here.

You are seeing `root` appear in the first task because you are running the playbook as `root` which is fine.

The other two tasks are `root` because you are giving privilege escalation to each task which will override the `become_user` that you are setting. You can simply remove **`become: yes`** and switching the user should work.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:

    - shell: whoami
      register: c

    - shell: whoami
      become_user: myuser
      register: d

    - debug: var=c.stdout

    - debug: var=d.stdout
```

Comment: Copying your exact example to my script and running it still results in the user being root. So I'm afraid that doesn't work either.

Comment: It turns out that this is right the issue is that I had the following in my groupvars file unbeknownst to me: ansible_become_user: root
ansible_become_method: sudo

Comment: I would like to mention that even `become: no` should NOT be used as well. In my case, `become: no` override my `become_user`, thus `whoami` output the ssh-user instead of the one specified in my `become_user`

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for ansible still running as root even when become_user: is set to non root user.

1. Navigate to ~.
2. Delete the .ansible directory "sudo rm -r .ansible".
3. If running individual tasks in playbook with command "sudo ansible-playbook /vagrant/provisioning/playbook.yml --tags "taskname_tag"", remove "sudo".
4. Now some tasks might have issues running if they need to be root - so give the individual tasks root privileges with "become: true".

That should be it, its what worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

try to add

```
 become_method: su
```

It might help to use the certain user. Im not sure, it might help

Comment: Check the third example - I've used that. It doesn't seem to make any difference oddly :(

Comment: ah yes, I see now. :-(

Comment: This is on CentOS 8.3 if that should matter (I don't think it should though)